# Allowing Google Calendar to read Other calendars

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I'm developing an application in Java, which connects to Google Calendar API through service account. The login is working well.
I also have a Google account with Calendars. Some of them are "My Calendars" and some of them are "Other Calendars".

I can share "My Calendar" to the service account, using the service account's email, and my app can read these calendars and events.

Nevertheless, I can't read "Other Calendars" with this service account.
I know that I can manually take the Id's of those "Other Calendars" and read it with this service account, but my app does not in advanced these id's (I want it to be dynamic).

Basically, I want that a user in my organization will add calendars to this Google account ("Other Calendar"), and my app will read these calendars through service account (and not client, in order to avoid user's authentication to read the calendar data, unless the authentication is happened once for good?).

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Other calendars means do you mean to say other users calendars? If you want your service account to access other users calendar, those calendars should be shared with the service account or you have to go with Oauth authentication.

Comment: @SGC, Not necessarily, it could be the calendar that Google provides you. You can add built-in calendar. For example, open "Other calendar" menu, choose "Browse interesting Calendars" and you can add those calendars to your UI.